# How to close cmd window with command?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I make a program on cmd with 2 windows and I want to close one cmd window with a command.

```
if %choise%==1 goto menu 
:menu
cls
color a
echo ===============================
echo              MENU
echo ===============================
echo   1.Eixt  2.History
echo.
set /p choise=Choose:
if %choise%==1 exit
if %choise%==2 goto History
```

can anyone help?

Comment: This is not a "program", it is a batch file. So you close the window by ending the batch file, not with some magic "close" command. And the code has absolutely nothing to do with the question. Nowhere does this code create a second command prompt window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I want to close one cmd window with a command

```
rem if %choise%==1 goto menu
```

The above line will cause an error if `%choise%` is not defined so remove it.

> goto was unexpected at this time.

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
:menu
cls
color a
echo ===============================
echo              MENU
echo ===============================
echo   1.Exit  2.History
echo.
set /p choise=Choose:
if %choise%==1 exit
if %choise%==2 goto History
endlocal
```

- If you press <kbd>1</kbd> the batch file will exit the `cmd` shell
- If you press <kbd>2</kbd> you will get an error as there is no label `history`

  > The system cannot find the batch label specified - History

---

#### I have two windows, "MWprog" and "History Box"

> I want to close the "History box" window without closing the "MWprog" windows.

Add the following command to the batch file:

```
taskkill /f /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq Administrator:  History Box"
```

Note:

- The extra space - there are two after the `:` - **is required**.

Comment: yes but this is a part of the program and i want to close an another cmd window that is running on my screen before goto menu label

Comment: @koskasFree4All Then you need to edit your question and explain properly what you want.

Comment: @koskasFree4All What is the title of the other cmd window?

Comment: i have to windows."MWprog" and "History Box" and i want to close the History box without closing the MWprog

Comment: @koskasFree4All Add TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq History*" at the start of the batch file.

Comment: @koskasFree4All Please feel free to [accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it answers your question.

Comment: I take this error 

ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'Administrator: History Box*'.
Type "TASKKILL /?" for usage.

Comment: Ok. Use the following (note the extra space - there are two after the `:` is required). `TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Administrator:  History Box"`

Answer (score 0):

To exit a batch use goto :eof [End of File]

```
if "%ShouldIExit%"=="TRUE" goto :EOF
```

or

```
if "%ShouldIExit%"=="TRUE" exit
```

or

```
if "%ShouldIExit%"=="TRUE" exit 2
Rem exit 2 will set the errorlevel to 2, and exit the program.
```

or

Search for this program on your computer, usually deep in the windows directory.

```
TaskKill.exe
```